# How to use a public method from a controller to another controller in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 2 controllers, Listes.php and Campagnes.php. I want to use a method from the Listes controller in a method from the campagnes, is it possible? And is it possible to pass some parameters to it?

I use Codeigniter 3.

I tried some answers I found here but none of them worked.

I also this in the campagnes.php controller :

```
    include_once (dirname(__FILE__) . "/Listes.php");

     class Campagnes extends Listes {

       public function listes_recap()
       {
         $result = parent::add($parameter1, $parameter2);
       }

      }
```

and in the Listes.php controller :

```
    class Listes extends CI_Controller {

     public function add($parameter1, $parameter2)
     {
       code here...
     }

    }
```

Thanks in advance for you're help.

Comment: Have you tried $this->add($parameter1,$parameter2); ?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to achieve the results you want. But calling one controller from another is NOT the way to go. The "best" way to do it depends on what actually happens in the function that both controllers will use.

The first way is to create a "helper" that each controller will load and then use.

**file: /application/helpers/list_add_helper.php**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('add'))
{
    function add($parameter1, $parameter2)
    {
       code here...
    }
}
```

Use it in the controller like this

```
$this->load->helper('list_add');
$result = add($one, $two);
```

The second way is to create a custom library (class)

**file: /application/libraries/List_adder.php**

```
class List_adder
{
    public function add($parameter1, $parameter2)
    {
       //code here
    }
}
```

Used in any controller

```
$this->load->library('list_adder');
$result = $this->list_adder->add($one, $two);
```

If you need to use CI code in your custom library you have a little more work to do. Read all about it [HERE](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html).

Answer (score 0):

calling one controller method from another controller is not a good programming  strategy